# How to check one json array value is present or not in another array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need one help. I need to verify weather one json array value is present inside another array or not using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
$img=array(
    array("iamge"=>"1234_asd.jpg"),
    array("iamge"=>"1235_ase.jpg"),
    array("iamge"=>"1236_asf.jpg")
);
$imgArr=array(
    array("iamgename"=>"1234_asd.jpg"),
    array("iamgename"=>"1235_ase.jpg"),
    array("iamgename"=>"1236_asf.jpg"),
    array("iamgename"=>"1237_asg.jpg")
);
```

Here I have two array. I need to check any of value from `$imgArr` array is present inside `$img` array or not.In case any value is not present it will return `false with that image name` and if all present it will return omlu `true`. Please help me.

Comment: There is no [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) in your question.

Comment: The approach obviously is to iterate over `$imgArr` and search for each elementinside `$img` (for example using `array_search()`). You store the overall result in a variable which you output at the end of the iteration process.

Answer (score 0):

```
$match = array();
foreach ($imgArr as $imgArray){
foreach ($img as $imgg){

    if($imgArray['iamgename'] == $imgg['iamge']){
        $match[]=$imgArray['iamgename'];
    }
  }
}

print_r($match);
```

Comment: @ zeljka :It printing the blank array.

Comment: sorry my mistake, I fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

```
function bjsearch($img, $seachimg){
    $result = true;
    if(!in_array($seachimg, $img)){
       $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}


$found = true;
$image_name = '';
foreach($imgArr as $k=>$im){
    $seachInArr = isset($img[$k]) ? $img[$k] : array();
    $res = bjsearch($seachInArr, $im['iamgename']);
    if($res === false){
       $found = false;
       $image_name = $im['iamgename'];
    }
}
var_dump($found, $image_name);
```

Working Example: https://3v4l.org/vkAF4